# set images as avatar using radio buttons in paperclip

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I am using paperclip gem in my web application to set avatar of user. It is working fine but for me the problem is we have to use following code

```
 <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
```

So it gives **choose file** button & then we can browse & select image to upload as avatar file. That is all fine but I want to give default images to set as avatar & user can select one of them via radio button. Is it possible to do so? Please guide me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I create labels for radio inputs and use the images as the background image for the label

```
<div>
<input type="radio" name="avatars" value="0" id="radioID1" style="float:left" />
<label for="radioID1" class="avatar avatar3"></label>
<input type="radio" name="avatars" value="0" id="radioID2" style="float:left" />
<label for="radioID2" class="avatar avatar4"></label>
</div>
```

this will look like this:

[image: taken from my website]